# Error: projects:list is not a Firebase command

Tags: firebase, firebase-cli

I have just installed the Firebase CLI and updated to the latest version following the [docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cli#mac-linux-npm).

They say I can list my Firebase projects using the command:

> firebase projects:list

But this gives me the error:

`Error: projects:list is not a Firebase command`

I am authenticated via the CLI and using Firebase CLI v7.0.0 and Node v10.20.1.

How can I list Firebase projects?

Comment: It works fine for me.  Please edit the question to be more clear about what you did to install the CLI, and state the version of it when you run `firebase --version`.

Comment: Thanks I have updated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using a very old version of the Firebase CLI.  The latest version is 8.4.0.

Answer (score 0):

Updating to Firebase v8.4 fixed the issue